# Remotely load <track> element in HTML video

Tags: html, reactjs, video, video-reactjs

I can't seem to load remote VTT files into an html5 video player (in ReactJS, using video-react v 0.11.2 (https://github.com/video-react/video-react)

```
<track
    kind="subtitles"
    label="English subtitles"
    src={api.makeFileURL(this.props.chapterPart.VideoFile[0].subtitles, this.props.user.id)}
    srcLang="en"
    default={true}
/>
```

This doesn't work.  The makeFileURL method creates a url to the vtt file.  Example: http://localhost:3000/api/file/download/5b1932c7f4717028c0b5d711-1529538217239-nicks.vtt?access_token=Q4tBHTC36Rumijnvsb9QruNlQJ5EX1mQPBLD86LHFHfJU3ttXOzCdOJBeqIj6xP9

When I access that file in my browser, I can see the file, and the mimetype is VTT.  When I include the file into my project, and load it locally into the track element, everything works fine.

```
<track
    kind="subtitles"
    label="English subtitles"
    src="/static/media/5b1932c7f4717028c0b5d711-1529538217239-nicks.vtt"
    srcLang="en"
    default={true}
/>
```

Thought it was a cross origin issue.  So I added crossOrigin="true" to the Player element, which in turn passes that prop to the html5 video element, but as I watch the network tab in FF or chrome, I never see the file being requested when it's a remote url.  When it's a local url, the file shows up in the network tab and everything works as it should.

There are no errors, just, the text track won't load remote files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was to dynamically load the track element after metadata load.  So in my code, where I call this.refs.player.load(), right after this, I have the following (working) code:

```
let self = this;
this.refs.player.video.video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function() {
    // We can't dynamically load <tracks> for subtitles, so we have to hook into the onload of the video...
    let track = document.createElement("track");
    track.kind = "captions";
    track.label = "English";
    track.srclang = "en";
    track.src = api.makeFileURL(self.props.chapterPart.VideoFile[0].subtitles, self.props.user.id);
    track.addEventListener("load", function() {
        this.mode = "showing";
        self.refs.player.video.video.textTracks[0].mode = "showing";
    });
    this.appendChild(track);
}, true);
```